# Is it okay to use "to have a picture of something" when you mean having an idea and a qualitative understanding of sth?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms, phrase-requests

I want to use "to have a picture of ..." in a sentence like this:

> to have a picture of this process we applied some theory to the system ...

Which by "to have a picture" i mean to have a qualitative understanding of the process. does this phrase makes sense and is used with this meaning? if not what are the appropriate phrases instead?

Comment: I think "*To* ***get*** *a [better] picture of this process*" is more common.

Comment: @cobaltduck No if this is a common idiom i prefer to use this. I just wanted to be sure that this is common. But if there are some literal phrases it would be nice to know them. thank you

Comment: @cobaltduck Actually, "to get a picture" can be literal.  Many mathematicians and physicists visualize the solution to a problem first as a picture, and then develop the equations.

Comment: I think the primary allusion in this metaphoric usage is that when you get a *picture* of something, you're *seeing it all at once* - with all the "sub-elements" having spatial relationships to one another, reflecting their real-world (causal) interactions/interdependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "(to) [get (the/a) picture](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/get-the-picture)" is an idiomatic way of saying "understand," originating from the idea of forming a clear mental visualization, i.e. picture, of a concept.

Other, more literal ways of phrasing this might be:

- To better understand this process, we...
- To conceptualize this process, we...
- To help us to visualize this process, we...